# TypeError: module is not a function AngularJS & Jasmine and protractor

Tags: angularjs, gulp, protractor

I have the following in my app.js

```
require('angular');
var http = require('http');
var fillDropDownsController = require('./js/controllers');
var getDropDownsService = require('./js/services');
angular.module('app', ['fillDropDownsController', 'getDropDownsService']);
```

my ng-app is on the html tag. I am using gulp-protractor to write the unit tests.

In my test file, I have mentioned the following:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    module('app'); });
```

But this keeps on giving the error as follow when i run my gulp command:

```
Message:
    Failed: module is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: module is not a function
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a library that you forgot to require? protractor is unable to identify the module function which must be a gulp function i guess.

Comment: Maybe you are missing `angular-mocks.js` from the dependencies of your runner?